# Excel - Parsing data to template

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I'm not sure if this is possible in Excel.

I have a sheet that looks like:

```
+---------------+-------+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|               |              August            |            September          |
+---------------+-------+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| Week Starting | 04/08 | 11/08  | 18/08 | 25/08 | 01/09 | 08/09 | 15/09 | 22/09 |
+---------------+-------+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| Monday        |       |        |       |       |       |       |       |       |
+---------------+-------+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| Tuesday       |       |        |       |       |       |       |       |       |
+---------------+-------+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| Wednesday     |       |        |       |       |       |       |       |       |
+---------------+-------+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| Thursday      |       |        |       |       |       |       |       |       |
+---------------+-------+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| Friday        |       |        |       |       |       |       |       |       |
+---------------+-------+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| Week Extra    |       |        |       |       |       |       |       |       |
+---------------+-------+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| Week Total    |       |        |       |       |       |       |       |       |
+---------------+-------+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

(The real sheet has all the months.)

And raw data that looks like:

```
+------+------+----------+
| DDMM | Year | Quantity |
+------+------+----------+
| 0408 | 2014 |        2 |
| 0708 | 2014 |        7 |
| 0509 | 2014 |       12 |
| 0508 | 0000 |        6 |
+------+------+----------+
```

I need to parse the raw data and add it to the calendar table.
The first data row would add 2 to the Monday under "04/08".

If the year is 0000 I need to add the number to the "Week Extra" for the correct week.

Is this possible?

Thank you

Comment: In the first table the year is not given anywhere. Or do you mean the current (system time) year?

Comment: Oh, forgot to say, the raw data will always be either 2014 or 0000. A new excel document will be created for each year.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to convert the dates in your raw table to actual excel dates. From the actual excel date you can extract the text for the day of the week, the text for the month, and the week starting date, which you can convert back to text to match your table. The formulas for doing this are in the screenshot below (because it's too verbose to type).

[image]

To get these into your calendar table, you could do a couple of things. A pivot table, from which you could use `=getpivotdata()` to extract values for each cell in the calendar is one method. I prefer, instead, to use `=sumproduct()` since it has less overhead. Formulas are in the screenshot below and a quick explanation follows.

[image]

`=sumproduct()` can test multiple conditions for true/false, across a range of values (in this case, testing the conditions for each row), and then sum the results of another range when all the conditions are true for the row. Here we are testing that E2:E5 contain the DD/MM in J2, that F2:F5 contain the Month Text in J1, and that G2:G5 contain the WorkDay text in I3. If all conditions are true, then it grabs and sums the value in C2:C5. One word of caution with this formula, your ranges that you are testing have to ALWAYS be the same length. You can't test E2:E5 for DD/MM and F2:F20 for the Month. Sumproduct will throw an error.